# difference between installing oracle-instantclient with conda install oracle-instantclient tsnames

Tags: conda, cx-oracle

When installing oracle-instantclient for ubuntu

**What is the difference between installation with conda or ubuntu:**

I am sure it is completely different. I just want to use some python scripts that access to an oracle server. 
Options:

1. Ubuntu install instructions for ubuntu
2. Conda installation

#### 1. Ubuntu install instructions

> Installation
>
> See the Instant Client Home Page for more information about Instant
>   Client packages.
>
> Client-server version interopability is detailed in Doc ID 207303.1.
>   For example, Oracle Call Interface 12.2 can connect to Oracle Database
>   11.2 or later. Some tools may have other restrictions.
>
> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations require the Basic or Basic Light package.
> 2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2
> 3. Add this directory to the PATH environment variable. If you have multiple versions of Oracle libraries installed, make sure the new
>      directory occurs first in the path
> 4. Download and install the correct Visual Studio Redistributable from Microsoft. Instant Client 12.2 requires the Visual Studio 2013
>      redistributable. Instant Client 12.1 requires the Visual Studio 2010
>      redistributable. Instant Client 11.2 requires the Visual Studio 2005
>      redistributable.
> 5. If you intend to co-locate optional Oracle configuration files such as tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora, ldap.ora, or oraaccess.xml with Instant
>      Client, then create a subdirectory
>      C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2\network\admin
>
> This is the default Oracle client configuration directory for
>   applications linked with this Instant Client.
>
> Alternatively, Oracle client configuration files can be put in
>   another, accessible directory. Then set the environment variable
>   TNS_ADMIN to that directory name.
>
> 6. Start your application.
>      [Oracle source info](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html#ic_winx64_inst)

#### 2. Conda installation

```
conda install -c anaconda oracle-instantclient
```

Almost empy [source](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/oracle-instantclient) information for conda install link

I haven'f found any documentation yet

Answer (score 1):

For basic Python use on Ubuntu I would just follow the official cx_Oracle installation instructions:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

The cx_Oracle steps for using Instant Client zips are straightforward: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip-files

In general you should download the official Oracle Instant Client 'Basic' or 'Basic Light' packages so you know they have not been altered and you know what license you are under.  Since you are on Ubuntu, get one of the zip files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html (assuming you have 64-bit Python).

The steps you posted above are for Windows and not so useful for Ubuntu.